# state of art MAX-SAT solver for ising spin glass

Tags: optimization

What is the best MAX-SAT solver problems for Ising spin glass? I tried Scip-Max-sat and open-wbo. While open-wbo cannot solve the instance with only 27 variable Scip-max-Sat fail to solve the one with 200+ variables (while it can solve model with 100 variables in 30 secs).... I am not sure whether I have missed something or is it the state of art solution space for ising spin glass is 100+ variables.

Here's the test case I use:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qg9u20w040e7hpn/AACg428cWgNfqF6pQG36URCxa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're really interested in MAX-SAT, or in finding the ground state of an Ising spin glass (I suppose the two are equivalent if the spin coupling values are $\pm 1$, for example). In any case, if you're interested in algorithms that can find approximate solutions efficiently, you should take a look at the papers by Helmut Katzgraber at Texas A&M University.